# Error when compiling PDF using knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr, rstudio

When I try to compile a PDF using knitr I get the following error:

```
there is no package called 'knitr' Error: object 'opts_knit' not found
Execution halted
```

I'm using RStudio 0.97.332 and R version 2.15.3.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you need to install knitr.  That should be fairly obvious from the error message.

```
install.packages("knitr")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can:

```
install.packages("knitr")
```

or from *Rstudio*

*Rstudio > Tools > install packages.*

type **knitr** on the window **install packages** and install

In order to test if the package is installed try

```
library(knitr)
```

Comment: R is case sensitive - you should call `library` not `Library`.

Answer (score 0):

After installing knitr in R, do not forget to call it in a chunk somewhere before you use it.
I usually use my first chunk, right after \begin{document}, to call all libraries I use
i.e.

```
<<chunk0, >>=
library("knitr")
library("xtable")
...
@
```

Then a second chunk for knitr options.

Comment: You won't need to call `knitr` explicitly within a document you are intending to `knit` unless you have a very strange work process that does not actually load `knitr` onto the search path prior to calling `knit` (perhaps if you called `knitr::knit(....)`, but that would be a strange approach.